# Is there a Mean Value Theorem (in several variables) of the form $|f(x)-f(y)|\ge [\ldots]$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, mean-value-theorem

In the second chapter of Spivak's *Calculus in Manifolds* the following theorem is proved:

**Theorem:** Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a rectangle and let $f:A\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be $C^1$. If there is a number $M$ such that $|D_jf_i(x)|\le M$ for all $x$ in the interior of $A$, then
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\le n^2M|x-y|$$
for all $x,y\in A$.

I was wondering if there is a similar theorem where $|f(y)-f(x)|$ is in the "larger than" part of the inequality.

---

Letting
$$m=\inf |\partial_jf_i(x)|$$
then ***assuming*** $(y_j-x_j)\ge 0$ and $\partial_jf_i\ge 0$ in $A$, the Mean Value Theorem (in a single variable) gives

$\begin{align}
|f(y)-f(x)|^2 & =\sum_i\left(\sum_j(y_j-x_j)\partial_jf_i(z_{ij})\right)^2\\
& \ge m^2 \sum_i\left(\sum_j(y_j-x_j)\right)^2\\
& \ge m^2 \sum_i\left(\sum_j(y_j-x_j)^2\right)\\
& \ge m^2 \sum_i|y-x|^2\\
& = nm^2|y-x|^2.\\
\end{align}$

Therefore
$$|f(y)-f(x)|\ge \sqrt{n}m|y-x|.$$

Comment: Fix $x$ and $y$ and consider $g(t) = f((1-t)x + ty)$ as a function of 1-variable. The mean value tells you that $g(1)-g(0) = g^'(t_0)$ for some $t_0$. The express derivative of $g$ in therms of $f$.

Comment: @Salcio that does yield an equality, but I believe it works only for functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$.